# Java explicit type cast for the floating-point division

Tags: java, floating-point

I am not sure if I am using explicit type cast for the floating-point division in option 4 (Division). I need a little help understanding what is floating-point division.

I must use integers to store the 2 operands, a double to store the result.  You must use an explicit type cast for the floating-point division in option 4. Also use a switch statement to process the menu choices. After each computation

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleCalculator
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Calculates two integers 
   //  using values entered by the user.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Variables
        final int ADDITION = 1,SUBTRACTION = 2, MULTIPLICATION = 3,DIVISION = 4, EXIT = 5;
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, choice = 0;
        double dblNum1, dblNum2, result;
        String equation = "";

        do
        {
            //Processing
            equation = "";
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Choose from the following: ");
            System.out.println("1. Add 2 integers");
            System.out.println("2. Subtract 2 integers");
            System.out.println("3. Multiply 2 integers");
            System.out.println("4. Divide 2 integers");
            System.out.println("5. Exit");
            System.out.print("Enter choice: ");

            choice = scan.nextInt();

                if(choice < 5 && choice > 0)//keeps program from asking for two numbers if exiting
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");
                    num1 = scan.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");
                    num2 = scan.nextInt();
                }

            //switch for operations
            switch (choice)
            {
                case ADDITION:
                    result = num1 + num2;
                    equation = ((num1) + " + " + (num2) + " = "+ result);
                    break;

                case SUBTRACTION:
                    result = num1 - num2;
                    equation = ((num1) + " - " + (num2) + " = "+ result);
                    break;

                case MULTIPLICATION:
                    result = num1 * num2;
                    equation = ((num1) + " * " + (num2) + " = "+ result);
                    break;

                case DIVISION:
                    if(num2 == 0)//when denominator becomes zero
                    {
                        System.out.println("DIVISION NOT POSSIBLE");
                        break;
                    }
                    dblNum1 = num1;//convert int to double
                    dblNum2 = num2;
                    result = dblNum1/dblNum2;
                    equation = ((num1) + "/" + (num2) + " = "+ result);
                    break;

                case EXIT:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("YOU HAVE ENTERED AN INCORRECT CHOICE");             
            }
            //Output
            System.out.println(equation);
            System.out.println();
        }while(choice != EXIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that "implicit cast" is what happens when you assign a value to a new variable or a wider type, such as assigning an `int` expression to a `double` variable, which is what you've done.  An "explicit cast" is when you actually put the cast operator in your code, which is what Ted Hopp's answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not an explicit typecast. You would want to use something like this:

```
result = ((double) num1) / ((double) num2);
```

Actually, because of the widening rules for the `/` operator, you would only need one of those explicit casts, but there's no harm in having both. In fact, because the cast operator `()` has higher precedence than the division operator `/`, you could write it as:

```
result = (double) num1 / num2;
```

which combines an explicit cast of the numerator and an implicit cast of the denominator.

Comment: (double) makes it explicit?  Because it is converting from an int to a double (or re-defining its type)?

Comment: @JamesParker - There's no standard Java definition of _explicit type cast_, but it undoubtedly means that you have to have a [cast expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16), which involves the use of the cast operator `()`.

Comment: This makes more sense now.Thank you Mr. Hopp

Answer (score 0):

An explicit type cast is when you tell the compiler the *type* of the result of an expression. Normally you don't need to type cast because the result of the expression is already known.

For example:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int c = a + b; // The "type" of a + b is int. No explicit cast.
```

But we can explicity cast that expression to a different type:

```
int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE, b = 2;
double c = (double) a + (double) b; // Explicitly cast to avoid integer overflow.
```

The second version tells the compiler to convert `a` and `b` to doubles and then add them together. The result of this expression will also be of type double.

Like @Ted Hopp said, you don't need to explicitly cast both operands like this. Casting either `a` or `b` will have the same effect in this case.